# windows authentication using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, single-sign-on

I want to create an internal website, preferably in asp.net, that uses ajax calls for performing all operations.

The requirements are that the site should use windows domain authentication (to act as a single-sign-on solution) for verifying which user is sending the request. What is the best way to accomplish this in a secure fashion? I am open to a solution using https or cookies or anything else feasible.

( I would prefer regular ajax using jquery since I havent used asp.net ajax but if that solves some issues more easily, then let me know)

The current way I am doing this (not through ajax) is disabling anonymous access in iis and then getting the logged in username from asp.net, but this requires the site to perform postbacks, etc which i want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

An Ajax request is not different from any other HTTP request when it comes to authentication.

Your user will most likely be authenticated when they access the index of your site. Any subsequent request, Ajax or not, will be authenticated. There is nothing special to do, and your jQuery code will look just like what it normally looks.

Answer (score -1):

Windows authentication is checked on every request.
How this is checked depends which authentication method /provider is enabled and supported on the server (kerberos, ntlm, custom, etc)

Credentials are automatically sent over under certain rules (I believe intranet  trusted for IE, I dont recall what else outside of that).
Firefox will prompt you if I recall every time.

Check out:
http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/iis-security/5707/IIS-6-0-Windows-Authentication-401-Every-Request

The important thing to note is the browser and server will take care of this and prompt the user when necessary.

Also to note is I highly highly suggest ALL traffic is under an SSL connection at this point to prevent sniffing and credential stealing/token stealking (such as is extremely easy for basic auth)

You can enable this protection inside of IIS and use all file permissions or you can control this in your web applications web.config by enabling windows authentication. How this is accomplished though depends on your server config (kerberos support, etc)

Answer (score -2):

You should absolutely:

1. Use an https connection to transmit username and password
2. Authenticate on the server side, with asp.net
3. Leverage the asp.net session to as great an extent as possible.

If you're not familiar with ASP.Net ... well, consider this a good opportunity to learn :)

jQuery is great, but it's just a tool.  In this case, it's probably not the best tool for this particular job.

IMHO...

Comment: I know that i will need to use https and authenticate on the server side, but how do I pass the credentials in the first place and know what username reaches the server is really the username of the person opening the browser and not spoofed? and how do I leverage the asp.net session to the extent possible? I know what needs to be done sortof from a high level view, but not the specifics